# Need to translate Nginx directives to Apache of my website

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

I've problem converting this Nginx directives to Apache:

Nginx (now in production and it works)

```
location ~ /(.*?_trk_).*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|pdf|zip|woff|woff2|JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG|SVG|PDF|ZIP|WOFF|WOFF2) {
 expires 1d;
 rewrite ".*_trk_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)" -0000000$3#$3#$4#/img/trk_images/$1/$2/$3/$4;
 rewrite "-0*?((\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}))#([^#]*)#([^#]*)#([^#]*)" $uri break;
 try_files /imgn/csm/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7 /img/csm/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7 @notfound-csm;
}
```

Apache (my current translation, but does not it work :( )

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*?_trk_).*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|pdf|zip|woff|woff2|JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG|SVG|PDF|ZIP|WOFF|WOFF2)
RewriteRule ^.*_trk_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ -0000000$3#$3#$4#/img/trk_images/$1/$2/$3/$4
RewriteRule ^-0*?((\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}))#([^#]*)#([^#]*)#([^#]*)$ /imgn/csm/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7
```

This is an example of the image URI:
`http://images.domain.dev/_trk_dealer_37556_805784_bfgh54545y25203968.jpg`

The Nginx configuration is not mine, and I have to translate it on Apache ASAP, but I don't know how Nginx use # to split the $3 parameter: "`-0000000$3#$3#$4#/img/trk_images/$1/$2/$3/$4`"

## (Update) How it works the website for images

If the image URI is:

`http://images.domain.dev/_trk_dealer_37556_805784_bfgh54545y25203968.jpg`

The path is build in this way:

`/_trk_[1](dealer)_[2](37556)_[3](805784)_[4](bfgh54545y25203968.jpg)`

that image is saved inside the folder:

`/imgn/csm/00/80/57/84/805784/bfgh54545y25203968.jpg`

The parameter [3] is the ads id, and it is splitted in 4 folders:

`/imgn/csm`**`/00/80/57/84/805784/`**`bfgh54545y25203968.jpg`

How can I translate the Nginx directive to Apache correctly?
Is there a way to split into the pattern of the RewriteRule the parameter number 3 into 8 digit (00)/(80)/(57)/(84) with some Regex rules?

Thanks guys!
Michele

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem by myself, so I hope this could help someone in the future.

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*?_trk_).*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|pdf|zip|woff|woff2|JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG|SVG|PDF|ZIP|WOFF|WOFF2)
RewriteRule     ^.*_trk_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ -0000000$3_$3_$4_/img/trk_images/$1/$2/$3/$4 [C]
RewriteRule     ^.*-0*?((\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}))_([^_]*)_([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)_(.*)$ /imgn/csm/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7 [L]
```

[C] and [L] flags are not required in this case, it works anyway, but it's more clear if you have a VirtualHost file more complicated then mine.

I tried to make a solution with only one RewriteRule for this directive, but I didn't able to do that. If someone know how to do, i'm always here. Thanks!